# Passing command line arguments in C# Visual Studio by code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, args

I want to pass two parameters to the following code, by giving numbers not from command line in debug

For example I want pass 4 4 to the code using entered values from user not fixed in command line to the :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args  )
    {
        if (args.Length > 0)
            new Program(int.Parse(args[0] ));

        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Read();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably use the project properties to set the command line arguments. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1ktzfy9w%28v=vs.100%29.aspx But I'm not sure if that is what you're asking.

Comment: Are you asking how to accept user input (Console.ReadLine)? Or how to pass command line args when debugging?

Comment: i want  use the values from  console.readline not from debugging

Comment: In case you would need to support a bit more complex command line argument structures, I would recommend you http://docopt.org/ which provides command line parsing for multiple languages incl C, C++ etc. But do not get distracted by this too early, for your scenario there are for sure much simpler methods.

Comment: Ummm.... why are you creating a new Program class? That seems like a bad idea... Plus you aren't doing anything with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get user input in "arg" format, you use Console.ReadLine():

```
string[] userArgs = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
```

The Console.ReadLine gets the entire input string, then to get the array we call `.Split()`. I split on spaces just like standard command line. Other delimiters are also possible, just pass in a different character to the `Split` function.

Of course, you could stick to using normal command line args and have the user enter them as part of the program call (not normally done on Windows since few people use command prompt, but it would work).

MSDN for [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) in case you are interested!